# What is the symbol ! mean in typescript when initializing a variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on angular project , while editing the component.ts file example given by my teacher .
a line of code appears .

```
@Input() public searchType!: string;
```

It is inside the component typescript `OnInit()` function ,
I have no idea what the symbol ! means in this line of code and what is the effcts it brings .
As far as I know , it means not equals as an operator in language like php , java , but what does it mean when initializing a variable for typescript ?

Comment: I looked at the title , it seems that it should answer my question , when I google it , the link you shown is not on the result first page oddly , and when I post this question , the "similar question check" function didn't tell me , should I instantly delete this question , as it seems this violate the laws ....

Comment: Well technically it's a different operator when dereferencing than declaring a field. But all you need to know is that it's called the "non-null assertion operator" and you can find all the right docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!` - aka TypeScript's "[non-null assertion operator](https://medium.com/@tar.viturawong/a-note-on-typescript-non-null-assertion-operator-bad8fbe62bba)", is a way to tell typescript that you know for sure the value of a property is neither `null` nor `undefined`.

Note that this is potentially dangerous, since if the value does end up being `null` or `undefined`, it could result in unwanted behavior.
As you can infer, this is a way to "silence" typescript, and therefor should only be used if you are sure that it is correct for your use-case.

This is different to JavaScript's `?`, aka "[optional-chaining operator](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining)", which is a way of saying that the value might be `undefined`, and that in such a case, it should simply return an `undefined`.